# How to remove audio effects (gain, noise reduction, ...) when recording in an android app

Tags: android, delphi, audio, firemonkey

In FMX Delphi 11 I'm recording audio to process it.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
  FChannelConfig:= TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
  FAudioFormat  := TJAudioFormat.JavaClass.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
  FTailleBufferBytes := TJAudioRecord.JavaClass.getMinBufferSize(FSampleRate, FChannelConfig, FAudioFormat); 

  // VOICE_RECOGNITION
  AUDIO_SOURCE:= TJMediaRecorder_AudioSource.JavaClass.VOICE_RECOGNITION ;

  //UNPROCESSED Added in API 24
  if (TJBuild_VERSION.JavaClass.SDK_INT >= 24) then
  begin
    FAudioManager:= TJAudioManager.Wrap((TAndroidHelper.Activity.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.AUDIO_SERVICE) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    AudioMngrProp:= FAudioManager.getProperty(TJAudioManager.JavaClass.PROPERTY_SUPPORT_AUDIO_SOURCE_UNPROCESSED) ;
    if (Boolean.Parse(JStringToString(AudioMngrProp))) then
    begin
      AUDIO_SOURCE:= TJMediaRecorder_AudioSource.JavaClass.UNPROCESSED ;
    end;
  end;

  // Init FAudioRecord
  FAudioRecord := TJAudioRecord.JavaClass.init(AUDIO_SOURCE, FSampleRate, FChannelConfig, FAudioFormat, FTailleBufferBytes);

  // Start recording
  (FAudioRecord As JAudioRecord).StartRecording;
```

In some Android devices, I have bad levels on a different ways: 10 times greater, 4 times lower, levels reduction on low frequencies, ...
So I decided to get all informations about audio effects being used by Android and try to disable it in my application. Doing this I hope to fix my errors levels in my app.

The problem is that I got issues having these informations.

I tried to get infos from an TJAudioEffect and TJAutomaticGainControl class but I don't know how to use it.

```
  FAudioEffect:= TJAudioEffect.Wrap((TAndroidHelper.Activity.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.AUDIO_SERVICE) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID) ;

  FAutoGainCtrl:= TJAutomaticGainControl.Wrap((TAndroidHelper.Activity.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.AUDIO_SERVICE) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID) ;
```

With David's answer, I can test TJNoiseSuppressor and TJAutomaticGainControl:

```
TJNoiseSuppressor.JavaClass.isAvailable
TJAutomaticGainControl.JavaClass.isAvailable
```

When creating an TJAutomaticGainControl object I have to get ID from FAudioRecord, AUDIO_SESSION_ID_GENERATE doesn't work and I don't understand why:

```
//FAutoGainCtrl:= TJAutomaticGainControl.JavaClass.create(TJAudioManager.JavaClass.AUDIO_SESSION_ID_GENERATE) ;
  var sessionID:= FAudioRecord.getAudioSessionId() ;
  FAutoGainCtrl:= TJAutomaticGainControl.JavaClass.create(sessionID) ;
```

I have an exception when creating equalizer object:
Cannot initialize effect engine for type

```
FEqualizer := TJEqualizer.JavaClass.init(0, sessionID);
FEqualizer := TJEqualizer.JavaClass.init(0, (TAndroidHelper.Activity.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.AUDIO_SERVICE) as ILocalObject).GetObjectID) ;
```

SessionID is not null.

I thought it was a permission problem. In the manifest, I have to add the MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

This permission don't need to be request at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`AutomaticGainControl` is created by using the `create` class method, e.g.:

```
  if TJAutomaticGainControl.JavaClass.isAvailable then
    FAutoGainCtrl := TJAutomaticGainControl.JavaClass.create(TJAudioManager.JavaClass.AUDIO_SESSION_ID_GENERATE);
```

As per the [documentation for `AudioEffect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect), you create an instance of one of the descendants, e.g.:

```
  FEqualizer := TJEqualizer.JavaClass.init(0, LSessionID);
```

where LSessionID is what the name implies.

Comment: Thank you Dave but I have some problems with TJEqualizer; it couldn't be created.